# Encrypt HTTP post parameters from JSP to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, encryption, parameters

I have a login JSP which takes username / password from the user in text boxes and on submit it forwards the username/password parameters to Login Servlet using POST method.

Now I am using Paros Proxy in between (as Man-In-The-Middle attack) to trap the parameters. The parameters received from JSP are captured in Paros as plain text.

Is there any specific method provided by Java standard API which we can use to encrypt  these parameters such a way that:

1. Even if the parameters are captured by Paros Proxy, it may not be able to display in plain text.
2. Servlet do not have to decrypt it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You certainly don't want to just "encode" them. You want to "encrypt" them, which is an entirely different thing. Encoded information can be decoded without some security key (e.g. URL encoding, character encoding, HTML encoding, etc). Encrypted information can't be decrypted without some security key. I've fixed the wrong terminology in your question.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for removing the boldness, it was little too much emphasis for my taste!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSL to protect your data from being sniffable. If you require that no decoding (probably meaning *decrypting*) is to be performed on the server side, I cannot think of any other way.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried using SSL with my tomcat using this link, but it is showing certificate error (may be bcoz no cert from CA). But still it runs on HTTPS  with certificate error.. but surprisingly Paros can look into those parameters as well in plaintext.. no luck with SSL either :-(

Comment: Why not try and use Apache HTTPD for SSL handling? Connecting it to servlet containers like Tomcat is quite easy, and there is plenty of documentation for each and every configuration aspect.

Comment: SSL is the answer to your question. You need to concentrate on solving your concrete certificate problem. Feel free to ask a new question about that step (on serverfault).